# Switch chrome console to specific frame automatically

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to automatically switch the frame of the javascript console to one belonging to a chrome extension when I refresh the page?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @KayceBasques See [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-ui?hl=en) under 'Selecting the right target'. A chrome extension creates its own frame, I have to select the frame to interact with the extensions js variables in the console. Unfortunately, every time I refresh the page I have to select the extension's frame again.

Comment: @KayceBasques just checked your profile, sorry my explanation wasn't aimed at your knowledge in this area. I dont mean it to sound insulting!

Comment: I updated that doc recently :) I meant an example page with different frames. I'll just find an arbitrary example and link to it if I find anything useful for you.

Comment: @KayceBasques Oh okay, thanks :). [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp) is a webpage with multiple frames.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not, to my knowledge the execution context will always start at the `top` frame.

Additionally, there doesn't seem to be any programmatic method of accessing the Console tab to change that from a DevTools extension.

Comment: Arg its such a pain to have to switch the context after every reload :(